Is it necessary to specify the device type (Android or iOS) when sending push notifications from a Django server through Firebase in a Flutter app?
I am trying to send notifications and I am receiving on Android but on iOS I also uploaded the APNS key also on firebase, when send notifications there is success message on server and no error.
I was expecting to find information on whether specifying the device type is necessary for proper notification delivery and if it impacts the notification payload. Specifically, I want to know if failing to specify the device type could result in notifications not being delivered correctly or if Firebase handles this automatically.
